# How to get the index of last word with an uppercase letter in PHP

Tags: php, regex, substring, offset, uppercase

Considering this input string:

> "this is a Test String to get the last index of word with an uppercase letter in PHP"

How can I get the position of the last uppercase letter (in this example the position of the first "P" (not the last one "P") of "PHP" word?

Comment: You said "could I get the position of the last uppercase letter" and in the parenthesis you are mentioning the first "P" of the "PHP" word which is not the last uppercase letter. So what you really need? Also, have you tried anything to share?

Comment: This seems to work https://regex101.com/r/KkJeho/1

Comment: Wait.. what do you mean by position? As in a count of chars you get from strpos? Why did you the tag this regex? Regex does not give you a count

Comment: @user467801 Your question is at risk of being "unclear what you are asking".  There are many ways to solve your question, but we can't be absolutely certain about accuracy without more detail.  Please provide 3 to 5 more sample inputs that present edge-case scenarios and your expected output for each.  This will help volunteers to understand the variability of your text and allow us to confidently write a solid pattern/solution for you.  The better your question, the better our answers.

Answer (score 4):

I think this regex works. Give it a try.

https://regex101.com/r/KkJeho/1

```
$pattern = "/.*\s([A-Z])/";
//$pattern = "/.*\s([A-Z])[A-Z]+/"; pattern to match only all caps word
```

Edit to solve what Wiktor wrote in comments I think you could str_replace all new lines with space as the input string in the regex.
That should make the regex treat it as a single line regex and still give the correct output.
Not tested though.

To find the position of the letter/word:

```
$str = "this is a Test String to get the last index of word with an uppercase letter in PHP";

$pattern = "/.*\s([A-Z])(\w+)/";
//$pattern = "/.*\s([A-Z])([A-Z]+)/";  pattern to match only all caps word

preg_match($pattern, $str, $match);


$letter = $match[1];
$word = $match[1] . $match[2];
$position = strrpos($str, $match[1].$match[2]);

echo "Letter to find: " . $letter . "\nWord to find: " . $word . "\nPosition of letter: " . $position;
```

https://3v4l.org/sJilv

Comment: `"/.*\s([A-Z])/"` will work unless the string is multiline and the last *capitalized* word is on the line other than the first one. Or if the capitalized word is just preceded with a non-word char other than whitespace. BTW, doesn't OP want to match only ALLCAPS words?

Comment: @Wiktor true. But I have no idea what OP want. He also says "position" which makes reges more or less useless.

Comment: @Wiktor I think I have solved both of your concerns :-)

Comment: Also, that won't work if it's a one word sentence. Changing it to `.*\b[A-Z]` will solve that **and** if the preceding letter isn't a space - i.e. `Written in PHP/Java`. Another issue with this is that **it doesn't answer the question**! This matches/finds the last capitalized word/letter, but it doesn't give the **position** of that character.

Comment: @ClasG We can probably nitpick this and all other regexes. Yes it's true it does not work on one word sentences. Nor does it work with `/`. Do you know what? It wont work on hard drive paths either because that is a backslash. And it wont work on comma separated files, or colon separated. And it wont work on double names such as Anna-Maria, or who knows, maybe it does? Maybe it is the A, that is the "find". Since the question has a poor desription of what he/she needs and a bullshit example string that most likely is not close to what is actually used we can't know what regex to create.

Comment: Patterns need to be exact, since the question is vauge at the very best. How are we supposed to create an exact pattern? And yes it does not answer the question. That is why I asked in comments above is it position or not he/she wants? I have not yet got an answer. Nobody knows what he/she wants. Do you?

Comment: Whoa... Take it easy. I just made a suggestion that I believe would improve your regex slightly, and pointed out a fact. It's not like I accused you of scheming to steal the crown jewels ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you also want to consider a non-regex version: You can try splitting the string at the whitespace character, iterating the resulting string array backwards and checking if the current string's first character is an upper case character, something like this (you may want to add index/null checks):

```
<?php    

$str =  "this is a Test String to get the last index of word with an uppercase letter in PHP";
$explodeStr = explode(" ",$str);
$i = count($explodeStr) - 1;
$characterCount=0;
while($i >= 0) {
    $firstChar = $explodeStr[$i][0];
    if($firstChar == strtoupper($firstChar)){
        echo $explodeStr[$i]. ' at index: ';
        $idx = strlen($str)-strlen($explodeStr[$i] -$characterCount);
        echo $idx;
        break;
    }
    $characterCount += strlen($explodeStr[i]) +1; //+1 for whitespace
    $i--;
}
```

This prints `80` which is indeed the index of the first `P` in `PHP` (including whitespaces).

Comment: I find this a good answer. Why was it downvoted? It actually gives the position, which mine does not. And is regex free which (unless it's a high string) probably makes it faster. +1 from me!

Comment: I guess because the question was actually tagged as regex..but thanks! :)

Comment: The OP does not decided method in my opinion. If that was the case there would be hundreds of threads with regex answers on parsing html. But there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas' pattern looks pretty solid, but this will find the position faster...

```
.* \K[A-Z]{2,}
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KkJeho/5)

Here is the PHP implementation: [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da27d8364009a6f0442634a23bb28a3b2016434b)

```
$str='this is a Test String to get the last index of word with an uppercase letter in PHP test';
var_export(preg_match('/.* \K[A-Z]{2,}/',$str,$out,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)?$out[0][1]:'fail');
// 80
```

---

If you want to see a condensed non-regex method, this will work:

Code:  [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce49241709bd5847c6516079e321717f56c72169)

```
$str='this is a Test String to get the last index of word with an uppercase letter in PHP test';
$allcaps=array_filter(explode(' ',$str),'ctype_upper');
echo "Position = ",strrpos($str,end($allcaps));
```

Output:

```
Position = 80
```

This assumes that there is an all caps word in the input string.  If there is a possibility of no all-caps words, then a conditional would sort it out.

---

Edit, after re-reading the question, I am unsure what exactly makes `PHP` the targeted substring -- whether it is because it is all caps, or just the last word to start with a capitalized letter.

If just the last word starting with an uppercase letter then this pattern will do:  `/.* \K[A-Z]/`

If the word needs to be all caps, then it is possible that `/b` word boundaries may be necessary.

Some more samples and explanation from the OP would be useful.

---

Another edit, you can declare a set of characters to exclude and use just two string functions.  I am using `a-z` and a space with `rtrim()` then finding the right-most space, and adding `1` to it.

```
$str='this is a Test String to get the last index of word with an uppercase letter in PHP test';
echo strrpos(rtrim($str,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '),' ')+1;
// 80
```